# Calculate real and imaginary part of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

So the task is to calculate the real and imaginary part of this complex number.

$z=\frac{e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}{1+i}= \frac{e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}\cdot(1-i)}{(1+i)(1-i)}=\frac{1}{2}(e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}\cdot (1-i))=\frac{1}{2}(e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}\cdot \sqrt2\cdot e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}})=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$

How did they get to this part: $\frac{1}{2}(e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}\cdot \sqrt2\cdot e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}})$?

I calculated it by using $e^{i\phi}=cos(\phi) + i \cdot sin(\phi)$ with $\phi= \frac{\pi}{4}$ here.

But could someone explain how they got this, I'm a little confused right now?

Comment: They chose to express $1-i$ in polar form. Do you know how to do that? They could also have opted to expand $e^{i \pi /4}$ like you did. Both ways are valid, and you should probably be able to convert both ways.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd have put $1+i$ into polar terms from the start and not bothered with the multiplying by conjugates.  But it wouldn't make any difference.  Or you can convert $e^{i\frac \pi 4}$ to rectangular terms first.  But then synthetic division is nowhere near as easy as polor coordinate division.

Comment: By the way, who is the "they"?  "They" did it correctly but IMO they took dang near the least direct and least clear possible way of doing it.  (Once you not $\cos \frac \pi4 = \sin\frac \pi 4$ we have $e^{i\frac \pi 4} = r + ir$ for $r$ for a constant you get it is $r$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $z=\frac{e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}{1+i}= \frac{e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}\cdot(1-i)}{(1+i)(1-i)}=\frac{1}{2}(e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}\cdot (1-i))=\frac{1}{2}(e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}\cdot \sqrt2\cdot e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}})=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$

> How did they get to this part: $\frac{1}{2}(e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}\cdot \sqrt2\cdot e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}})$?

It appears that you are only asking the narrow question:

How can the following be demonstrated ?

$$(1 - i) = \sqrt{2} \times e^{-i\pi/4}.$$

By definition,

$$e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta).$$

$$\cos(-\pi/4) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, ~~\sin(-\pi/4) = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

Therefore

$$e^{-i\pi/4} = \cos(-\pi/4) + i\sin(\pi/4) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \left[i \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right].$$

Therefore,

$$\sqrt{2} \times e^{-i\pi/4} = 
\sqrt{2} \times \left\{ ~\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \left[i \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right] ~\right\}$$

$$ = (1 - i).$$